# Creating overlap interval data in R

Tags: r, intervals

I am trying to create data with overlapping intervals.
My data set is:

```
A B 
2 20 
3 40 
5 60 
6 90
```

and I want to get:

```
A1 A2 B1 B2 
2  3  20 40
3  5  40 60
5  6  60 90
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for the small example and your desired output. I suppose you have tried to [search on SO and other places](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What to search for?  I believe "lag" or "lagging" will get you going. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(x, embed, dimension=2))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    2   40   20
[2,]    5    3   60   40
[3,]    6    5   90   60
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put your data into a matrix (or convert it to a matrix) then you can use the `embed` function, possibly with a little bit of rearranging:

```
> mydat <- cbind( A=c(2,3,5,6), B=c(20,40,60,90) )
> embed(mydat, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   40    2   20
[2,]    5   60    3   40
[3,]    6   90    5   60
> embed(mydat, 2)[,c(3,1,4,2)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    3   20   40
[2,]    3    5   40   60
[3,]    5    6   60   90
```

Comment: (+1) How does embed select the column to order? I was surprised by `mydat <- cbind(B=c(30,10,100,90),A=c(2,3,5,6));embed(mydat,2)[,c(3,1,4,2)]`

Comment: `my.expectation <- matrix(c(10,30,90,30,90,100,3,2,6,2,6,5),3,4)`

Comment: @dayne, it takes values in the order given, if you need them sorted you need to presort them yourself.  `embed` is used for lagging in time series, so it assumes that the order given is the one wanted, the fact that it can be used for ranges in this case is a nice side benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Very manually:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,5,6),B=c(20,40,60,90))
df2 <- data.frame(A1=t(combn(df1$A,2))[,1],A2=t(combn(df1$A,2))[,2])
df2 <- df2[which(!duplicated(df2[,1])),]
df2$B1 <- df1[match(df2[,1],df1[,1]),2]
df2$B2 <- df1[match(df2[,2],df1[,1]),2]
> df2
  A1 A2 B1 B2
1  2  3 20 40
4  3  5 40 60
6  5  6 60 90
```